# "Use for App service" parameter in Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell

In the Azure Application Gateway UI, when creating a HTTP Setting, there's a tickbox called "Use for App service":

[image: UI]

I'm trying to replicate this HTTP Setting in PowerShell using the following command:

```
   Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name $MaintenanceToggleHTTPSetting -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Protocol Http -Port 80 -Probe $probe
```

Having checked the documentation, I can't find any parameter to replicate this.

Is it possible? Is it a combination of other parameters perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no parameter for `Use for App service` option in the powershell command.

Besides, I found something weird, on my portal, I choose the `Use for App service` option ->`Save`, exit and enter again, then the option will not be chosen.  Not sure  if I do it right, if not, please correct me.

Also, I catch the request with `choose the option/not choose` via `F12`, after comparing, I find the request body is the same.

**Edit**:

We need to choose the `pick hostname from backend address` option in `probe`, then the `Use for App service` option will be saved.

Here is a specific powershell script as a supplement for the ansewer of @dunc, if someone waht to use `Use for App service` option, you could refer to it. For more details, refer to @dunc 's answer.

```
$AppGw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "joygateway" -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp"
$probe = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -Name "testprobe" -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name "testsetting" -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Protocol Http -Port 80 -Probe $probe -PickHostNameFromBackendAddress -CookieBasedAffinity "Disabled"
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
```

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: I encountered the exact same problem Joy. If you set the "custom probe" and "pick hostname from backend address" options together however, I think you might find the tickbox saves after exiting? Either way, it's clearly not working properly and it's very poorly labelled/documented.

Comment: @dunc Find that, I need to choose the `pick hostname from backend address` option in probe, then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a response from Microsoft this, which I have tested and confirmed:

```
The checkbox ‘Use for App service’ is a wrapper for 2 checkboxes followed by it.
So when you  configure both checkboxes below it to ‘on’, this “use for App service” becomes active.
```

Basically, set the `-Probe` and `-PickHostNameFromBackendAddress` parameters when creating the HttpSettings. This ticks the "Use for App service" tickbox in the UI.

Comment: I have added a specific powershell script in my answer for other community members to find, thanks for your sharing.:-)